# A stored procedure which returns a collection of a custom complex type

Tags: entity-framework

I have to create some sub complex types from  the stored procedure's returning columns.
I mean some columns are result of some operation (like addition or subtraction) which I want to compute them i application (because it makes large sub queries if I make them in stored procedure).
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create stored procedure returning columns you want to get from the database.
2. Import the stored procedure in *Update from database wizard*
3. Go to model browser and create function import for that stored procedure
4. Select complex type as return value (it can create complex type for you)
5. Create your partial part of class generated for the complex type and create all properties you want to compute in your application

Steps 1-4: [How to import stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx)

Btw. this is possible only with EFv4.x with EDMX.